# Why withdraw() function is working only once in my python Tkinter code?

Tags: python, tkinter

I created several windows in Tkinter. I want to close them by button clicking and with this step open a new one. The problem is withdraw() function is working only at the first window. So, why the other windows are not closing?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

class window:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.MyButton = Button(master, text='Go to 2th page', command=self.dunno)
        self.MyButton.pack()

    def dunno(self):
        self.goTo2th_page = Toplevel(root)
        root.withdraw()
        self.MyButton2 = Button(self.goTo2th_page, text='Go to 3th page', command=self.dunno2)
        self.MyButton2.pack()

    def dunno2(self):
        self.goTo3th_page = Toplevel(root)
        root.withdraw()
        self.MyButton3 = Button(self.goTo3th_page, text='Go to 4th page', command=self.dunno3)
        self.MyButton3.pack()

    def dunno3(self):
        self.goTo4th_page = Toplevel(root)
        root.withdraw()
        self.MyButton4 = Button(self.goTo4th_page, text='End', command=self.close)
        self.MyButton4.pack()

    def close(self):
        self.goTo4th_page.destroy()

val = window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Because you used `root.withdraw()` instead of `self.goTo2th_page.withdraw()` and else.

Comment: That's the result when somebody use capy-paste.. cant believe I did not recognizing it.. Thank you